# Unix: File have 28 columns separated by space, print column 8 unique values with sum of column 16 to column28

Tags: unix, awk, sed

Sample File.txt:
[image]

```
"Object_Type" "710" "30" "14" "Partner" "Rpt" "Cool" "0ICPRP900" "Des_Space" "HBBREX" "soon_Type" "FY28" "Jan" "50" "USD_US" #Mi #Mi #Mi 0.006641 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
"Object_Type" "710" "30" "14" "Partner" "Rpt" "Cool" "0ICPRP 900" "Des_Space" "HBBREX" "soon_Type" "FY28" "Jan" "50" "USD_US" #Mi #Mi #Mi 0.01 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
"Object_Type" "710" "30" "14" "Partner" "Rpt" "Cool" "0ICPRP A&B_900" "Des_Space" "HBBREX" "soon_Type" "FY28" "Jan" "50" "USD_US" #Mi #Mi #Mi 0.641 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Looking for output line:

```
0ICPRP900 0.006641
0ICPRP 900 0.01
0ICPRP A&B_900 0.641
```

I have tried below command and it's printed column 8 (column not printed after have space special char )

```
awk '{a[$8]+=$17+$18+$19+$20+$21+$22+$23+$24+$25+$26+$27+$28}END{for (i in a) 
print i,bc a[i]}' File.txt
```

Output:

```
"0ICPRP900" 0.006641
"0ICPRP 0.01
"0ICPRP 0.641
```

Any suggestions how to get unique column8 (column8 with in "") with sum of column 16 to Column 28

Comment: When you say `unique column8` - are you saying in your real data that some of the $8 values can occur multiple times in the input but you only want then printed once? If so then [edit] the sample input/output in your question to include such cases.

Comment: And please don't put images or links in your question, just show us concise, testable sample input/output than we can copy/paste to test with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using any awk:

```
$ awk -F'"' '{n=split($31,f," "); sum=0; for (i=4; i<=n; i++) sum+=f[i]; print $16, sum}' file
0ICPRP900 0.006641
0ICPRP 900 0.01
0ICPRP A&B_900 0.641
```

Or using GNU awk for FPAT and gensub():

```
$ awk -v FPAT='"[^"]*"|[^ ]+' '{sum=0; for (i=19; i<=NF; i++) sum+=$i; print gensub(/"/,"","g",$8), sum}' file
0ICPRP900 0.006641
0ICPRP 900 0.01
0ICPRP A&B_900 0.641
```

or if by `unique column8` you mean you want to sum the values for multiple occurrences of the same $8 value across the input file you can do either of:

any awk:

```
awk -F'"' '
    {
        n = split($31,f," ")
        for (i=4; i<=n; i++) {
            sum[$16] += f[i]
        }
    }
    END {
        for (key in sum) {
            print key, sum[key]
        }
    }
' file
```

GNU awk:

```
awk -v FPAT='"[^"]*"|[^ ]+' '
    {
        for (i=19; i<=NF; i++) {
            sum[gensub(/"/,"","g",$8)] += $i
        }
    }
    END {
        for (key in sum) {
            print key, sum[key]
        }
    }
' file
```

Comment: I have made some changes and it's working as expected.


awk -F'"' '
    {
        n = split($31,f," ")
        for (i=0; i<=n; i++) {
            sum[$16] += f[i]
        }
    }
    END {
        for (key in sum) {
            print key " ;"  sum[key]
        }
    }
' file
Thank You :)

Comment: You're welcome. Yeah, unfortunately with your sample input and expected output it wasn't clear if you wanted the sum per line or across all lines as the expected output given that input is  the same either way. I assumed the former but apparently you wanted the latter.

Answer (score 1):

With GNU `awk`, you could try following. Written and tested with your shown samples.

```
awk -v FPAT='"[^"]+"|[^"]*' '
{
  sum=0
  num=split($NF,arr," ")
  for(i=1;i<=num;i++){
    sum+=arr[i]
  }
  gsub(/"/,"",$15)
  print $15,sum
}
' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk -v FPAT='"[^"]+"|[^"]*' '  ##Starting awk program from here, setting FPAT to set fields as per requirement.
{
  sum=0                        ##Nullifying sum here.
  num=split($NF,arr," ")       ##Splitting last field into array here.
  for(i=1;i<=num;i++){         ##Traversing through all elements of arr here.
    sum+=arr[i]                ##Creating sum from array elements.
  }
  gsub(/"/,"",$15)             ##Removing all " here
  print $15,sum                ##Printing 15 field along with sum here.
}
' Input_file                   ##mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Output will be as follows:

```
0ICPRP900 0.006641
0ICPRP 900 0.01
0ICPRP A&B_900 0.641
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for reply with work around solution.

Comment: I have to print column 8 unique values.

awk -v FPAT='"[^"]+"|[^"]*' '
{
  sum=0
  num=split($NF,arr," ")
  for(i=1;i<=num;i++){
    sum+=arr[i]
  }
  gsub(/"/,"",$8)
  print $8,sum
}
' File.txt|sort|uniq > res.txt

Output I got: All column8 values with sum 
I can see Column7 as well.

Comment: @John, please give example here for same.

Comment: awk -v FPAT='"[^"]+"|[^"]*' '
{
  sum=0
  num=split($NF,arr," ")
  for(i=1;i<=num;i++){
    sum+=arr[i]
  }
  gsub(/"/,"",$8)
  print $8,sum
}
' file.txt|sort|uniq

Output: 
0ICPRP 0
0ICPRP900 0

Source File: I have attached file.

Comment: @John, Please post your samples in form of text in your question, attaching images/links is NOT encouraged, since we need to test solutions, kindly do update it in your question, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You really have there is a form of [CSV](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4180) and it would serve well to use a proper parser for CSV. It is a surprisingly complex format...

The lightest weight CSV parser commonly available at the command line is Ruby (but Python, Perl work well too...)

Here is a Ruby:

```
ruby  -r csv -lane '
   BEGIN{ options={:col_sep=>" ", :quote_char=>"\""} }
   CSV.parse($_, **options)
    { |r| puts "#{r[7]} #{r[18..27].inject(0){|s,x| s+x.to_f}}" }' file
```

Prints:

```
0ICPRP900 0.006641
0ICPRP 900 0.01
0ICPRP A&B_900 0.641
```